# Is there a way to get sbcl to print out the value of a CPU register?

Tags: assembly, common-lisp, x86-64, cpu-registers, sbcl

Is there a way I can get SBCL to take the value of a CPU register at a certain point in my program and print it as an integer?

Would I have to use gdb?

Comment: What do you need this for? In the middle of a Lisp function, you can never be sure what a specific register is being used for so printing the content of a specific register wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Please clarify why you need to know the value of a CPU register. In general, it is not very useful to know register values since they are managed by compiler.In SBCL you can define VOPs (Virtual machine OPeration) with assembly code - see http://sbcl-internals.cliki.net/Adding%20VOPs.

Comment: I'm trying to write a program vulnerable to a buffer overflow, and code to exploit that by overwriting the return address on the stack.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Why do you try to do that though? If you're trying to create a pathological example, using C or assembly should be a lot easier.

Comment: @Cubic, just to prove to myself it can be done in CL, and maybe learn some things along the way.  I'm already convinced I could do it in C.  I'm fairly certain in can be done in CL but it would still be nice to actually see it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can access CPU registers by using [VOPs (Virtual Operations)](http://sbcl-internals.cliki.net/VOP). In VOPs you can write code also in assembly, so in that sense you can use VOPs like gcc extended assembly.

So, here's an example VOP and a related function for executing it. The `get-cpuid-eax` VOP receives two unsigned 32-bit arguments as input, stores them in `eax` and `ecx`, executes `cpuid` instruction, and returns the value of `eax` register after the `cpuid` to `get-cpuid-eax` function that called the VOP. The `get-cpuid-eax` function then stores the value in `*result*`. You can print the value easily with `(format t "~a" *result*)`.

Note: there is some problem (bug in SBCL or in my code?) that causes this code not to execute without problems always. Recompiling and reloading usually helps. I have confirmed the `cpuid` `eax` output with both `gcc` extended assembly and running a x86-64 assembly program in `gdb`. All give the same results for same values in `eax` and `ecx`.

**Edit:** changed function & VOP names to `get-cpuid-eax` to avoid confusion with variable names.

**Edit:** fixed code formatting with slimv.

```
(sb-vm::defknown get-cpuid-eax
                 ((unsigned-byte 32) (unsigned-byte 32))
                 (unsigned-byte 32)
                 (sb-c::foldable sb-c::flushable sb-c::movable))

(sb-vm::define-vop (get-cpuid-eax)
  (:policy :fast-safe)
  (:translate get-cpuid-eax)
  (:args
    (my-eax :scs (sb-vm::unsigned-reg) :target eax)
    (my-ecx :scs (sb-vm::unsigned-reg) :target ecx))
  (:arg-types sb-vm::unsigned-num sb-vm::unsigned-num)
  (:temporary
    (:sc sb-vm::unsigned-reg :offset sb-vm::eax-offset)
    eax)
  (:temporary
    (:sc sb-vm::unsigned-reg :offset sb-vm::ecx-offset)
    ecx)
  (:results
    (my-result :scs (sb-vm::unsigned-reg)))
  (:result-types sb-vm::unsigned-num)
  (:generator
    0
    (sb-vm::move eax my-eax)
    (sb-vm::move ecx my-ecx)
    (sb-vm::inst cpuid)
    (sb-vm::move my-result eax)))

(defun get-cpuid-eax (my-eax my-ecx)
  (declare (type (unsigned-byte 32) my-eax my-ecx)
           (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
  (defparameter *result* (get-cpuid-eax my-eax my-ecx)))
```

Some websites with short VOPs which I found very useful while coding this:

[Dmitry Kaliyanov's article "Добавление примитивов виртуальной машины SBCL" ("Adding primitive virtual machines of SBCL", in Russian)](http://lisper.ru/articles/sbcl-add-vop)

[the Lisp code for Dmitry Kaliyanov's article (above)](http://lisper.ru/apps/format/138)

[Dmitry Ignatiev's blog entry: SBCL, x86, SSE (in Russian)](http://love5an.livejournal.com/355007.html)

[Christophe Rhodes' presentation slides (pdf): Unportable but fun: Using SBCL Internals](http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas01cr/talks/2009-05-28%20Milan/slides.pdf)

[kurohuku's blog entry: "SBCLでCPUID" (in Japanese)](http://kurohuku.blogspot.fi/2009/11/sbclcpuid.html)

[swap-bytes source code file sbcl-vops.lisp](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=I_wCnWaAPDmkEZXGU5xjPHan1Hg&cid=JR-T9Jqewb4&s#L0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you storing the result in `*result*` instead of returning it? And why a `defparameter` inside a `defun`?! And is there a particular reason to have `(safety 0)`?

Comment: @DanRobertson My answer is a proof of concept (that it can be done), not enterprise-level code. You are free to post your own answer.

Comment: I suppose I was expecting a reply like “if you don’t do X then the vop won’t kick in”

Answer (score 1):

Another source of a cpuid example (that supports 64bit too) is from the excellent stmx library for CL.

- [the defknown form](https://github.com/cosmos72/stmx/blob/9a704e142216015783e8bb1f8d7cb8d90a14f6f9/asm/compiler.lisp#L113)
- [the vop](https://github.com/cosmos72/stmx/blob/9a704e142216015783e8bb1f8d7cb8d90a14f6f9/asm/x86-32%2C64-vops.lisp)
- [the wrapper function](https://github.com/cosmos72/stmx/blob/9a704e142216015783e8bb1f8d7cb8d90a14f6f9/asm/cpuid.lisp)